# AngularJS nested directives with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to build a table based on dynamic data (columns & rows).

The goal is to have a reusable component which can be designed mostly from within the template html file.

```
<rows repeat = 'row in data'>
<cell key = '"key"' value = 'row.value'></cell>
<cell key = '"key2"' value = 'row.value2'></cell>
</rows>
```

*note: key is a static name, it should be set from within the template and isn't part of this question.*

The output should be something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat = 'row in data'>
<td>{{row.value}}</td>
<td>{{row.value2}}</td>
</tr>
```

And of course it should be parsed(?) at the end.

I've found out that transcluding isn't the right way to go:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874#issuecomment-46410994
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7842#issuecomment-46416336

Based on these comments I've started my own Plunker. I get the feeling that I'm getting there (hopefully), but I can't seem to get it working all together.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yr7qVn3fSt82RXPNBV6l?p=preview)

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample directive that will accomplish what you want:

```
myApp.directive('myTable', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'MyTable.html',
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },  
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.keys = [];
      for (var key in scope.items[0]) {
        scope.keys.push(key);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

You can use this directive like this:

```
<my-table items="people"></my-table>
```

Where the html attribute items="<blah>" is an array of objects that you want to make up your table. For instance, I could assign the array

```
people = [{name: 'John', occupation: 'Programmer'},
{name: 'Jill', occupation: 'Analyst'},
{name: 'Jeff', occupation: 'Sales'},
{name: 'Joan', occupation: 'Designer'}];
```

to `items` (like I did in the example above) and it would create a table with that information.

We are using a `templateUrl` in our directive, the html for that template looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="key in keys">{{key}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td ng-repeat="value in item">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This creates a table who's first row is a list of column headers that corresponds to the property names of the objects in the array. It then creates a new row for each item, and iterates their values for each column.

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Me1KtRErluEUV3T3r9iH?p=preview

In order to better understand how to use directives, I recommend reading through the documentation for directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi pje thanks for your reply. However I need to work with nested directives of which the first directive will have a reference to the scope data object. The cells to use will be set in the template and need to be inserted in the parent directive after parsing. The cell directives will be dynamic based on other variables.

Comment: @RoyMilder You'll have to give me the specific behavior you want to see before I can help you any further. Give an example of what you would want to see on screen given a particular set of data. Thx!

Comment: Hi pje! Thanks! Did you see the plunker at the end of my question? I think that should give you some insight

Comment: @RoyMilder I looked through your plunker for a while, and I am pretty sure that what I posted above can address your issue. You can update the table dynamically using two-way binding. I updated my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Me1KtRErluEUV3T3r9iH?p=preview, it now includes some inputs for adding new people. I am not sure why you are trying to use the $templateCache for this, or why you are trying to nest your `row` and `cell` directives separately instead of creating a single template. Neither of those seem necessary. Anyway, best of luck, hope this helps.

Comment: i've figured it out, see my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With some guiding on the AngularJS git I finally figured it out.

**Goal**

Create a reusable component for creating tables based on dynamic data. The table styling, cell properties etcetera needs to be done in the template.

**Solution**

So let's say I have two sets of data:

Set 1: list of people attending. The list consists of a "name" column, "age" column and a "attending" column. Name is readonly, age a editable input and attending needs to be a set of radio buttons (yes, no).

Set 2: list of members. The list consists of a "name", "invited". Name is readonly, "invited" a group of radio buttons.

In one template, both tables are displayed. The only thing that needs to be done is adding the data object to the current scope and adding the table with minimal markup in the template.

Data sets

```
$scope.attending = [{name: "Roy", age: 30, attending: "Yes"}, {name: "Thomas", age: "29", attending: "No"}];
$scope.members = [{name: "Roy", invited: "Yes"}, {name: "Thomas", invited: "No"}, {name: "Mary", invited: "No"}, {name: "Hanna", invited: "Yes"}];
```

Table 1 / Set 1:

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Attending</th>
  </tr>
  <tr row rows = 'attending'>
    <td cell type='readonly' key='name'></td>
    <td cell type='input' key='age'></td>
    <td cell type='radio' key='attending'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Table 2 / Set 2

```
<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </tr>
  <tr row rows = 'members'>
    <td cell type='readonly' key='name'></td>
    <td cell type='radio' key='invited'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The whole component can be seen here:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yr7qVn3fSt82RXPNBV6l?p=preview)

It's not completely finished yet, but I'm getting there. This component should work with the ngTable library as well.